# PermissionError(13, 'Отказано в доступе')

Tags: python

В общем имеется такой код для шифрования файлов, можно назвать чем-то типа вируса)
И если запускать через консоль (py main.py) или через интерпретатор, то проблем не возникает, и он спокойно, как должен, шифрует все файлы.
Но, если через *pyinstaller* скомпилировать его в .exe файл, то возникает ошибка доступа. Уже пытался и просто запустить от имени Администратора и в *pyinstaller* указывать флаг *--uac-admin*, но не работает никак. Программа не может удалить файл в *encrypt() os.remove(filename)*
Есть у кого-нибудь идеи, почему именно через .exe файл у программы возникает ошибка доступа?

Если что - файл предварительно не открывается; это именно файл, а не папка (проверка os.path.is_file); у файла не стоит атрибут "Только чтение"

```
import pyAesCrypt
import os
import msvcrt


def unlock_file(filename: str):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        fd = f.fileno()
        size = os.path.getsize(filename)
        msvcrt.locking(fd, msvcrt.LK_LOCK, size)
        msvcrt.locking(fd, msvcrt.LK_UNLCK, size)


def encrypt(filename: str, encrypt_password: int):
    """Функция шифрования данных"""
    buffer_size = 512 * 1024
    pyAesCrypt.encryptFile(filename, f'{filename}.crp',
                           encrypt_password, buffer_size)
    unlock_file(filename)
    os.remove(filename)
    print(f'[INFO] Encrypted: {filename}')


def walking_by_dirs(dirname, encrypt_password):
    for name in os.listdir(dirname):
        path = os.path.join(dirname, name)

        if name == 'main.py' or name == 'FileEncryptor.exe' or name == 'FileDecryptor.exe':
            continue

        if os.path.isfile(path):
            try:
                encrypt(str(path), encrypt_password)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f'[ERROR] {repr(e)}\n  [PATH] {path}')
        else:
            walking_by_dirs(path, encrypt_password)


def main():
    password = input('encrypt password /> ')
    walking_by_dirs(os.curdir, password)
    input('Press Enter to continue...')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Напишите простейшую программу на питон, которая в зависимости от входного параметра будет делать операции, которые вы подозреваете, запакуйте pyinstaller-ом, и проверьте, что не работает. Ну и заверните вызов `main()` в `try/except` и печатайте stacktrace.

Comment: достаточно просто собрать программу с консолью, тогда ошибки будут видны

Comment: Да. спасибо, Roman Konoval, я как-то не догадался этого сделать. Всё-таки проблема в os.remove(filename). В теории именно unlock_file(filename) должен был сделать так, чтобы ошибки не было, но что-то пошло не по плану.